# How do I render two inputs into one list in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to teach myself how to code and created a little todo app. In the rendering of each todo input I have the element and then a checkbox to click for it to be removed. I tried to create a separate input to give the amount of time it will take for each item to be created. When I tried to link that up to my rendering method, nothing renders and I have zero error messages.

```
import React from 'react';

class InputBar extends React.Component {
  state={ todo: '',
          time: null
        }

  onInputSubmit = e =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.todoSubmit(this.state.todo)
    this.props.timeSubmit(this.state.time)
    this.setState({
      todo: '',
      time: this.state.time
   })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="input-group mb-3">
        <form onSubmit={ this.onInputSubmit } >
          <label>Input Todo</label>
          <div className='input-control'>
            <input
              type='text'
              className="form-control"
              aria-label="Sizing example input"
              aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default"
              value={this.state.todo}
              onChange={e => this.setState({
                todo: e.target.value
              })}
             />
            <input
              type='number'
              required
              className='input-control'
              defaultValue={0}
              value={this.state.time}
              placeholder='How long will it take?'
              onChange={e => this.setState({
                time: e.target.value
               })} />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}; export default InputBar

    import React from 'react';
    import InputBar from './inputbar';

    class List extends React.Component {
      state = {
        list: [],
        nextId: 1
      };
      componentDidMount() {
          const list = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem( "list" ) );
          this.setState( { list } );
      }

     addToList = (todo, time, list) => {
        this.setState({
          list: [
            {
              name: todo,
              text: time,
              id: this.state.nextId

            },
            ...this.state.list,
          ],
          nextId: this.state.nextId + 1
        },
          () => {
            localStorage.setItem("list", JSON.stringify(this.state.list));
          });
      }

     removeFromList = (id) => {
        this.setState({
          list: this.state.list.filter(entry => entry.id !== id )
        },
          () => {
            localStorage.setItem("list", JSON.stringify(this.state.list));
          }
        );
      }

      renderList = () => {
        return this.state.list.map((element) => {
            return (
              <div>
                <li>
                  {element.name}
                  <input
                    style={{marginLeft: '15px'}}
                    type='checkbox'
                    onClick={()=> this.removeFromList(element.id)}
                  />
                </li>
              </div>
            )
        })
      }

      render() {
        console.log(this.state.todo, this.state.time)
        return (
          <div>
            <InputBar
              todoSubmit={this.addToList}
              timeSubmit={this.addToList}
            />
            <ul>
              { this.renderList() }
            </ul>
          </div>
        )
      }
    };
    export default List; 
   //this is then send to imported an app component to be rendered
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi & welcome to Stack Overflow, Elias.

You pass two handlers to your `InputBar` component that both resolve to the `addToList` handler defined in your list component. However, when you call these handlers, the arguments do not match what `addToList` is expecting, which is a list, a todo and a time.

You obviously don't *need* a list argument (it's never used in `addToList` as you manage the list present in that component state's anyway, which is fine), so `list` can be removed.

And in my opinion, you do not need 2 handlers (one for the todo, one for the time value). One handler that adds both todo AND time would be better (after all, the idea is to submit a todo as a whole object) and would line up with what `addToList` would expect.

In summary, here are the changes I suggest:

In `inputbar.js`:

```js
  onInputSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { todo, time } = this.state
    this.props.handleSubmit(todo, time)
    this.setState({
      todo: '',
      time: this.state.time
   })
  }
```

In your `List` component:

```js
     addToList = (todo, time) => {
       // just removed the unnecessary 'list' param
       // actual code left untouched
     }

     // other code

     render() {
       console.log(this.state.todo, this.state.time)
       return (
         <div>
           <InputBar handleSubmit={this.addToList} />
           <ul>
             { this.renderList() }
           </ul>
         </div>
       )
     }
```

Comment: Thanks Jaxx! I made the improvements that you mentioned and it is still not rendering any list elements. I added `{element.text}` to the renderList method. I am not sure if that is heading in the right direction or not.

Comment: @EliasWood I took a deeper look at it. In addition to the changes above, I had to comment out all the `localStorage` parts to get your code to work, see https://codesandbox.io/s/30w6y1jqnq. Reading LocalStorage in `componentDidMount` messed up with your list and made it non-iterable, so you might want to take a closer look at that. I couldn't see anything wrong with the way you dealt with localStorage, so it could be a CodeSandbox issue maybe? But apart from that, I could add/remove to the list and the list updated accordingly.

Comment: Jaxx I did not realize it but all I needed was to add a submit button. It worked on enter with one input but not two so adding a submit button did the trick. Thank you for taking a look at it!